# Substring causing index and length error

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring

I have a section in my code that I run to check to see if the item is an spanish item or english item. I am using this logic from an old vb.net application.

```
public int Spanish_Item()
{
    int i = 0;
    object j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    string ss = null;
    string sp_item = null;
    sp_item = TxtItem.Text.Trim();
    k = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        ss =  sp_item.Substring(i, 2);
        if (ss == "XX")
        {
            k = 1;
            i = 16;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

The following code loops around 
then I get this error message :

> ex.Message    "Index and length must refer to a  location within the
>   string.\r\nParameter name: length"     string

please help!!!

Comment: Looks like it caused by hardcoded  string length `15` which you pass as firts param for the  `.Substring` method. You should put the real length there.

Comment: How do you define Spanish text ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always go from 1 to 15 - if the (trimmed) text of `TxtItem.Text` is shorter then 15 chars you'll get the exception.

You should use the length-2 of `sp_item` as upper bound to avoid the error.
Also, instead of setting `i = 16` you should use `break` to stop the for loop.

However, I think your algorithm could also be written like this instead of the `for` loop:

```
if (sp_item.IndexOf("XX")>=1) {
    k=1;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer buddy

Answer (score 0):

In c# the first position is at index 0 not 1 like vb

```
public int Spanish_Item()
{
int i = 0;
object j = 0;
int k = 0;
string ss = null;
string sp_item = null;
sp_item = TxtItem.Text.Trim();
k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sp_item.len-2; i++)
{
ss =  sp_item.Substring(i, 2);
if (ss == "XX")
{
k = 1;
i = 15;
}
}
return k;
}
```

you can use

```
if (sp_item.IndexOf("XX")>=0) {
    k=1;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help buddy

Comment: @GMG The op states "from an old VB.NET application" - since this is a call to a .NET base library function the index must also be 0 based. However, if the original app was in fact VB6, VBA or similar, then you'd be right of course.